# Is it possible to ENCRYPT standard SOCKS5 proxies?

Tags: proxy, socks

HI, I am from a country with incredibly heavy internet censorship.
I managed to get some FREE socks 5 proxies like 12.34.56.78:8084. It works well. However, there are still some sites that cant be accessed.

I have done a search, and find out that "Standard Socks5 proxies do not encrypt the connection". Thats why some sites are still blocked. ["Compared to standart Socks 5 proxies SSH Socks encrypt your connection with a AES-256 bit data encryption." but SSH socks and VPN are not free.]

Is it possible to use a software to encrypt the Standard Socks5 proxies?

**Thanks a lot! If you come up with an idea, you are helping the whole country!**

Comment: Better suited for http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 3):

check out [shadowsocks](http://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html).
But you will need a VPS to run it I think.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my own question.
Here is the method:
Buy a VPS, Use SSH (Putty) and socks proxy together to encrypt communication.
Hope this helps other people.